# Dump from Mysql to elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We are using logstash to dump data from mysql to elastic search. I am trying to dump list of all payments against a userId(this will be my _id for the _type)

Elastic mapping looks like this

```
{
"Users": {
"properties" :{
  "userId" : {
    "type" : "long"
  },
  "payment" :
  {
    "properties":{
      "paymentId": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The sql table has userId, paymentId.

Which filter should i user to get the json output that i can feed to elastic search

Answer (score 0):

Use [jdbc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) Logstash input plugin.